# Não consigo exibir minhas informações no banco de dados?

Tags: php

segue abaixo meu código. Quando eu coloco minhas informações e clico em cadastra. porque minhas informações não aparecem no banco de dados?

```
---------Registrar.php-----------
<?php

    require_once "db.php";

    if(@$_GET['go'] == 'registrar'){
    $Nome = $_POST['Nome'];
    $Sobrenome = $_POST['Sobrenome'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Senha = $_POST['Senha'];


     $sql = "INSERT INTO `mycrush (`Nome`, `Sobrenome`, `Email`, `Senha`) VALUES ('$Nome', '$Sobrenome', '$Email', '$Senha')";
     $result = mysqli_query($sql);


      if (!$result) {
        echo "<h3>Desculpe, houve um erro ao registrar...</h3>";

      }else{
        echo("Dados inseridos com sucesso!");
        setcookie($Email,"login");
        echo "<script>alert('Usuário cadastrado com sucesso.');</script>";
        header("Location: login.php");    
     }
   }
?>

---------login.php-----------
<?php
    require_once "db.php";


        if(@$_GET['go'] == 'login'){
        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $Senha = $_POST['Senha'];
        $verifica = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM 'mycrush' WHERE Email = '$Email' AND password='$Senha'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($verifica)<0) {
            echo "<h3>Palavra-passe ou e-mail errados!</h3>";
        }else{
            setcookie($Email,"login");
            header("location: index.php");
        }
    }


?>

---------index.php-----------
<?php 

include("db.php");
echo "Se você conseguiu abrir está página é porque deu certo!!!!";

?>

---------db.php-----------
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
$db = mysqli_select_db($con, "clientes");

if(!$con) {
    die("Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados; " . mysqli_error());
}


?>
```

Comment: Para todas as chamadas de `mysqli_query()`  precisa passar a conexão como primeiro argumento

Comment: e como eu faço isso?

Comment: `mysqli_query($con, 'select ...')`